# How to remove the need to put .local on the end of domain names

Tags: macos, mac, networking, ssh, lan

I'm just wondering what setting to change to remove the need to put `.local` when SSH-ing to a computer on my home network. I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 and am sitting behind an airport base station extreme and am sharing a local IP.

example:

```
$SSH domain.local
```

this works just fine I want to be able to just

```
$SSH domain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a search domain under the advanced network settings should provide what you are looking for. Details are at http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/14127.html

For Linux/Unix hosts, this is achieved by a search path in /etc/resolv.conf. The domain is by default in the search path, although additional items can be added with a line such as:

> search localhost

Further details: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-dns-search-list-for-host-name-lookup/

Comment: setting it in the preferences worked like a champ, didn't know what that pane was for, but now I do. Thanks so much!